# Mysql) when i using user-defined variable , SQL explain use type "ALL"

Tags: mysql, variables, indexing

When i using user-defined variable , i want to use 'index' like 'ref..';

**for example,**

```
SET @company_code = "A002";

select *
from product_in_out 
where  company_code = @company_code
  and product_date = "2022-04-13"
  and out_type = "Q"
;
```

above result like this,
[enter image description here][1]

for using SQL index, i've tested that variable to plain text like "A002".

at that time, SQL use `index` like 'ref'

```
select *
from product_in_out
where  company_code = "A002"
  and product_date = "2022-04-13"
  and out_type = "Q"
;
```

if so, is there any good way to use valiable for using mysql Index?!?!

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE script. What index do you mean? `(product_date, out_type, company_code)` should be used. PS. Do not use double quote chars for enclosing the literals, use single quote chars only.

Comment: *when i using user-defined variable , SQL explain use type "ALL"* UDV value is treated as possibly changeable, not as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, add this composite index:

```
INDEX(out_type, product_date, company_code)
```

(I assume `product_date` is of datatype `DATE`.)